# Fake delivery and receipt of a BrokeredMessage Azure ServiceBus

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues, brokeredmessage

I have created an instance of a BrokeredMessage and want to test my code around it's deliverycount versus a queue's max delivery count. I don't want to standup a real queue to send and receive the message on, but the deliverycount property is not initialized until the message is delivered. How can I fake this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing a helper function called GetDeliveryCount that accepted a brokeredmessage as a parameter. This returned message.DeliverCount. For my unit tests, I just mocked this to return whatever I wanted.

Comment: Can you please provide me your sample? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to mock this out and have it work creating a wrapper for complete and abandon message. I was tripping on message.Complete() when unit testing without the wrapper.

Create a Class and Interface to handle the message actions.

```
    public class MainServiceBusClientWrapper : IServiceBusClientWrapper
    {
        public void Complete(BrokeredMessage message) => message.Complete();
        public void Abandon(BrokeredMessage message) => message.Abandon();
    }
```

Do this in your class that handles incoming service bus messages:

```
private IServiceBusClientWrapper _serviceBusWrapper;

_serviceBusWrapper.Complete(message);
```

Instead of:

```
message.Complete();
```

In your unit test you can do something like this to not fail on BrokeredMessage actions:

```
_serviceBusWrapper.Setup(p => p.Complete(It.IsAny<BrokeredMessage>()));
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> the deliverycount property is not initialized until the message is delivered. How can I fake this?

[BrokeredMessage.DeliveryCount property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deliverycount?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_DeliveryCount) is read-only, and the value of DeliveryCount will be increased after message is delivered. There is no easy way to mock the BrokeredMessage class, but Obvs.AzureServiceBus integration library seems provide a way to control over properties for the purpose of a particular test, you could try to implement your own mock/fake IMessagePropertiesProvider.

For more detailed information, please check the following links.

- [Obvs.AzureServiceBus](https://github.com/drub0y/Obvs.AzureServiceBus/wiki/Accessing-Azure-Service-Bus-specific-message-properties#unit-testing)
- [MessagePropertiesProvider sample](https://github.com/drub0y/Obvs.AzureServiceBus/blob/f62724218c4c10839aed257caa9a0ea1fc2fdb84/Obvs.AzureServiceBus/Infrastructure/MessagePropertiesProvider.cs)